# ¿Cómo puedo ordenar utilizando el Método Burbuja(BubbleSort) en interfaz gráfica?

Tags: java

Trabajo en una aplicación donde la interfaz gráfica luce como se muestra en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo ordenar los números que se enuentran ya ingresados en el `JList` o `JTextArea`? Ya tengo el algoritmo del método burbuja pero no sé muy bien cómo aplicarlo para que me ordene los elementos de esa lista.

Comment: Luce como si necesitaras ordenar la lista/arreglo interno que mantienes y actualizar los datos de tu `JList` con la lista/arreglo ordenado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que tienes el JList ya cargado con los valores a ordenar como en la imagen:

```
ListModel<Integer> listModel=jList.getModel();
int[] valores=new int[listModel.size()];
for(int i=0;i<listModel.size();i++) {
  valores[i]=listModel.getElementAt(i);
}
Arrays.sort(valores); //ya esta ordenada la lista de forma ascendente
```

Suponiendo que quieras ordenarla de forma descendente pues utiliza el método *public static  void sort(T[] a, Comparator c)* de la clase *Arrays*

Answer (score 1):

Toma el array donde están los valores, (o extrae los elementos y almacénalos en un array) pasa este array al método de ordenamiento, limpia el JList y luego vuelve a insertar los valores.